# DynamoDB begins_with query unsuccessful fetch

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following item in my db:

[image]

My pk is userId:string and my sort key is teamId#taskId#checkpointId

The endpoint on my BE (node) looks like this:

```
router.get("/user/:userId/:teamId/:taskId", async (req, res) => {
  const { userId, taskId, teamId } = req.params;
  const { success, data } = await getUserById(userId, teamId, taskId);
  if (success) {
    return res.json({ success, data });
  }

  return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "Error" });
});
```

and my handler looks like so:

```
const getUserById = async (userId, teamId, taskId) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: Table,
    KeyConditionExpression:
      "userId = :userId AND begins_with(teamId#taskId#checkpointId, :teamTaskId)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":userId": userId,
      ":teamTaskId": `${teamId}#${taskId}#`,
    },
    ScanIndexForward: true, // Sort by taskDate in ascending order
  };

  try {
    const { Items = [] } = await db.query(params).promise();
    return { success: true, data: Items };
  } catch (error) {
    return { success: false, data: null };
  }
};
```

I double checked to make sure the arguments are not undefined and my request is:

```
localhost:8000/api/user/123456/987/321
```

I'd like to get all checkpoints since I have a few, hence the begins_with, but for some reason, I'm not getting a successful response.

Comment: Not a JS-expert - the order of the parameters in your `router.get` line doesn't match the one in the line below it, is that a problem? Please test the getUserById function independently to figure out if the problem is in that function or the router logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

You're not getting a successful response because you're using a special character in your KeyConditionExpression.

This is what you currently have:

```
KeyConditionExpression:
      "userId = :userId AND begins_with(teamId#taskId#checkpointId, :teamTaskId)"
```

However, dynamo treats the `#` character differently in a KeyConditionExpression. The `#` characters signifies the start of a token to be substituted by an [ExpressionAttributeName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ExpressionAttributeNames).  This is very similar to how dynamo substitutes [ExpressionAttributeValues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ExpressionAttributeValues) for anything stating with the `:` character in your KeyConditionExpression.

In your case, you want dynamo to treat `teamId#taskId#checkpointId` as a single attribute name but that won't happen because of the `#` characters, dynamo would try to substitute value for #taskId and #checkpointId, and both would fail.

**The Solution:**

When you have special characters like #(or any other specified in the official reserved word list [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html)) in attribute names for your KeyConditionExpression, you should use the [ExpressionAttributeNames query option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ExpressionAttributeNames) to provide aliases for such attribute names. In your case, for example, the query would look something like this:

```
const getUserById = async (userId, teamId, taskId) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: Table,
    KeyConditionExpression:
      "userId = :userId AND begins_with(#SK, :teamTaskId)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":userId": userId,
      ":teamTaskId": `${teamId}#${taskId}#`,
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#SK": "teamId#taskId#checkpointId",
    },
    ScanIndexForward: true, // Sort by taskDate in ascending order
  };
  // ...other existing code
};
```

SK is an arbitrary term I chose to represent the sort-key attribute, it could be any other string of your choosing.

With this changes, you should get a successful response back.